# select records that x days left to their DATETIME formatted field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a `Test` Model that has these fields :

```
test_id
title
desc
start_date
end_date
```

`start_date` and `end_date` fields have DATETIME format.

Now I want to select all records that **10** (for example) days (or less) left to their  `start_date` ,and `end_date` has not come.

I think that I should to use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) PHP API extension but I do not know How.

Comment: $test = Test::where('start_date', '>=', Carbon->now()->addDays(10));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting your date mutator**

First of all set your `start_date` as an instance of `Carbon` in your `Test` model. This will allow you easy manipulation of the datetime object it stores and interaction trough the Laravel query builder.

**Building the query**

```
$date = Carbon::now()->modify('+10 days')->toDateString();
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$results = Test::where('start_date', '<=', $date)
           ->andWhere('start_date', '>=', $today)
           ->get();
```

`$results` should contain `Test` models with your specified information.